# reactjs context reducer increment data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to increment the array value inside the object.

I tried the code below but It's removing the garments array and replacing it with `shirts: Nan` value

```
export const initialState = {
    booking: {
       expPrice: 0,
       garments: [
        {
            shirts: 0
        },
        {
            pants: 0
        },
        {
            etc: 0
        }
    ]
},
bookings: []
};

export const bookingsReducer = (state, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT_SHIRT': {
        return {
            ...state,
            booking: {
                ...state.garments,
                shirts: state.shirts + 1 // how to increment 
            }
        };
    }
    default:
        return state
   }
}
```

Comment: @loop Because `state.booking.shirts = state.booking.shirts + 1;` is a state mutation, which is very anti-pattern in React and conventional Redux reducer functions.

Comment: Right. Maybe I shouldn't say anything before getting up from the bed. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to spread the properties of your `garments` array into your new booking object, however, as `state` doesn't have a garments property you'll be spreading `undefined` (which is a no-op). Moreover, if it did hold your array, you would be spreading the indexes of your array as keys to your new object. You're also adding a `shirt` property to your booking object, which you don't want to do as you want to keep this property inside the objects of your garments array.

Instead, spread the `state.booking` properties into your booking object, and then overwrite the garments property with a new array to be the mapped version of your current garments array. When you're mapping,  if you find an object with a `shirts` property, you can increment its value by adding one to the current value, otherwise, you can return the current object:

```js
return {
  ...state,
  booking: {
    ...state.booking,
    garments: state.booking.garments.map(
      obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('shirts') ? {shirts: obj.shirts+1} : obj
    ) 
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

You are spreading an undefined value `state.garments` that should actually be `state.bookings.garments`, so `garments` array isn't copied to the new state. Similarly, `state.shirts` is undefined and any mathematical operation with it results in a `NaN` value.

## Solution

You should shallow copy all nested state object properties.

For the given state:

```
{
  booking: {
    expPrice: 0,
    garments: [
      { shirts: 0 },
      { pants: 0 },
      { etc: 0 }
    ]
  },
  bookings: []
}
```

Reducer logic

```
case 'INCREMENT_SHIRT': {
  return {
    ...state,
    booking: {
      ...state.booking,
      garments: state.booking.garments.map((cat, i) => i === 0 ? {
        ...cat,
        shirts: cat.shirts + 1,
      } : cat),
    }
  };
}
```